# JavaScript push() issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Can you tell me please, why the final array does not have the last item of the initial array; it returns `[3, 6, 9, 2, 4, 6]`, and we are missing `'8'`.

```
let item = [123,456,789,12,34,56,78];
const tailAndHead = arr => arr.slice(1).reduce((a,v,i) => (a.push(arr[i]%10), a),  []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

```
tailAndHead = arr.map(a => a % 10);
```

Comment: You can just use `a` instead of `arr[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Remove slice(1).

```
let item = [123,456,789,12,34,56,78];

const tailAndHead = arr => arr.reduce((a,v,i) => (a.push(arr[i]%10), a),  []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should push the sliced array item. Please modify you code like this.

```js
let item = [123,456,789,12,34,56,78];
const tailAndHead = arr => arr.slice(1).reduce((a,v,i,b) => (a.push(b[i]%10), a),  []);
console.log(tailAndHead(item));
```